# Issue with the const keyword and methods declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying the new React Hooks API and I am wondering why this method declaration inside my function component is not working :

```
const Foo = (props) => {

    const [..., ...] = useState(...);
    ...
    onChange = (e) => { ... }
```

I got this error below

```
'onChange' is not defined  no-undef
```

[image]

but when i add the `const` keyword it works.

```
const onChange = (e) => { ... }
```

Comment: That looks like a lint warning, not a runtime error. Are you sure your code doesn't run?

Comment: yes @NikKyriakides i have add an images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax

```
const Foo = (props) => {/* */}
```

declares a normal javascript function and assigns it to the variable `Foo`. This is not to confuse with a class. You can't declare "properties" on it like you can with a class using the class property syntax. In a class you can e.g. do this:

```
class MyComp extends Component {
    onChange = e => {/* ... */}  // this declares `onChange` as a property

    render() {
        // you can use this.onChange here

        return (
            <input onChange={this.onChange} ... />
        )
    }
}
```

However with functional components this is not valid:

```
const MyComp = () => {
    // this is the body of the function

    onChange = e => {/* ... */};   // MyComp is not a class so you can't just declare proteries on it.
}
```

However this is correct syntax:

```
const MyComp = () => {
    const onChange = e => {/* ... */}; 
}
```

But it probably doesn't do what you think it does. It just creates a local variable `onChange` inside of the `MyComp` function. Therefore the error `onChange is not defined`. You assign a function to the variable `onChange` that you did not declare before using it. It first needs to be declared using the keyword `const`, `let` or `var`.

The code may still work even though you did not declare the variable because the interpreter is silently treating it as a global variable declaration which is likely not what you want.

Comment: thanks man but why it don't work on function body ? what is the reason ?

Comment: @Youssef Classes are instanciated resulting in Instances. Functions are called. This is fundamentally different. Instances have properties (which can be functions). Functions have a body with local variables inside of it. Although defining them using arrow functions looks similar syntactically it is just something completely different. You should maybe take one step back and first learn about javascript functions and classes because this is basic knowledge when working with any kind of modern javascript framework or even any kind of programming language that supports object-orientation.